# android how can I custom a class like View or Preference

Tags: android, xml

I notice that View and Preference has the feature that when you try to edit an xml file for them, the class names and attribute names can be suggested and this makes it easy to fill an xml for them. I'm working to define a class that use xml file as data source and I think it's perfect if it can work as View or Preference. I just noticed that both View and Preference has many "@attr" tag in the comment beyond their class define. But I really cannot find out how it works.

Comment: What are you looking for? `I'm working to define a class that use xml file as data source`: Could you elaborate this ?

Comment: @Henry ok, if i defined a subclass of View and then edit an layout xml file and use this class. when i edit it's attributes there would be some useful suggestion. and that's what i want. i want to define a class which is just subclass of Object and has this feature.